# Invalid cursor state inspite of using rs.next()

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I have a NetBeans Application that uses a MySQL Server. But whenever I try to access the data from the ResultSet returned by the Select query I get the Invalid Cursor State error inspite of the code being in a while(rsc.next()) loops. The code is:

```
Statement stt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
ResultSet rsc = stt.executeQuery("Select timing,Monday from Comps_1_B where timing!='08 to 09'");
while (rsc.next()) {
    if (rsc.getString(2).equals("")) {
        timel.add(rsc.getRow() - 1);
        rsc.next();
    }
}
```

The error is at rsc.getString().
The stacktrace is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid cursor state
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6956)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7113)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLGetDataString(JdbcOdbc.java:3906)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getDataString(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:5697)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getString(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:353)
    at project_4year.Labtiming11.labtime(Labtiming11.java:191)
    at project_4year.Main.newLaball(Main.java:832)
    at project_4year.Main.lmain(Main.java:32)
    at project_4year.MainPanel$4.run(MainPanel.java:470)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `rsc.next()` twice. Remove one in the while loop.

Comment: But I need to access alternate records so how do I do that

Comment: What do you mean by alternate records?

Comment: After every record that I access I want to skip the next one

Comment: check with isLast() and don't call next() if it is the cursor is at the last record.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `rsc.next();` inside the if block.

Comment: But I need to access alternate records so how do I do that

Comment: As simple as that,you can create coounter and increment it.